# Opening File with emacsclient from windows

Tags: batch-file, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I try to open a File from within Windows10 in an emacsclient running on wsl2/Debian.

Upon startup I launch wsl/debian, X410 as X-server and the emacs daemon.

I can start a new emacs frame with emacsclient with the following startclient.bat:

```
@echo off

debian.exe run "if [ -z \"$(pidof emacsclient)\" ]; then export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0; emacsclient -c; pkill '(gpg|ssh)-agent'; fi;"
```

Then I created a shortcut so I can open a new emacs frame from the taskbar. To my surprise it works quite smoothly... so far. However, I can not figure out how to open a file with the emacsclient from within windows explorer.

I guess I would need to pass an argument to the emacsclient -c in the bat file, but how do I do this?

EDIT:
by doing the following:

```
debian.exe run "if [ -z \"$(pidof emacsclient)\" ]; then export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0; emacsclient -c "%1"; pkill '(gpg|ssh)-agent'; fi;"
```

I can open a file with emacsclient with:

```
startclient.bat file.txt
```

However when using open with the path to the file is messed up
instead of

```
/mnt/c/Users/path/to/file
```

I get

```
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/C:\Users\path\to\file
```

How would I go about passing the correct path as variable?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure where the `/mnt/c/Windows/system32/` is coming from, but you can convert the `C:\Users\path\to\file` into `/mnt/c/Users/path/to/file` by surrounding the `%1` argument with [wslpath](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/), as in something like:

`emacsclient -c "$(wslpath '%1')"`